# how to get data from nodejs api in angular 4 and pass it to array?

Tags: angular

I wrote my Api in nodeJs. I got data from Api but that is in [[object Object],[object Object]] this format. and when i set this array to my array variable it gives empty array. please help me how to assign this array into my defined array variable?

my employee service`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
@Injectable()
export class EmployeeService {
private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:5000/Role';
constructor(private _http: Http) { }
getRoleData() {
    const url = 'http://localhost:5000/Role';
    return this._http.get(url)
        .map(x => x.json());
}
```

EmployeeComponent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Employee, EmployeeService } from './employee-service';
import { Role } from '../../Modules/Role.module';
@Component({
       selector: 'app-employee-master',
       templateUrl: './employee-master.component.html',
       styleUrls: ['./employee-master.component.scss'],
       providers: [EmployeeService]
})
export class EmployeeMasterComponent implements OnInit {
 roles: Role[] = [];
constructor(private employeeService: EmployeeService) {}
 ngOnInit() {
  this.employeeService.getRoleData().subscribe(x => this.roles = x);
  console.log("Role" + this.roles);
}

}
```

Role Module

```
export class Role {
public OID: number;
public RollNo: string;
public RollName: string;
public GCRecord: string;
public OptimisticLockField: string;

constructor(OID: number, RollNo: string, RollName: string, GCRecord: string, OptimisticLockField:string) {
    this.OID = OID;
    this.RollNo = RollNo;
    this.RollName = RollName;
    this.GCRecord = GCRecord;
    this.OptimisticLockField = OptimisticLockField;
}
}
```

my api response

```
[
  {
     "GCRecord": null,"OID": 1,"RollNo": "1","RollName": 
     "HR","OptimisticLockField": null
   },
  {
     "GCRecord": null,
     "OID": 2,
      "RollNo": "2",
      "RollName": "Admin",
      "OptimisticLockField": null
   }]
```

Comment: Can't help without code. Provide your component and service code...

Comment: thanks for reply. i added my code

Comment: This sounds like your nodejs api might not be returning in the correct format.  Try hitting it with your browser or through postman to ensure that the response from the service is correct.

Comment: Add this to your code and see what you get in console. 


`this.employeeService.getRoleData().subscribe(x => { console.log(JSON.stringify(x)); this.roles = x; console.log("Role" + JSON.stringify(this.roles));}; )`

Comment: i added my response json

Comment: after adding this i got my json data

Comment: but when i do this -                             
       this.employeeService.getRoleData().
          subscribe(x => {
              console.log(JSON.stringify(x));
              this.roles = x;
          });
      console.log("Role" + JSON.stringify(this.roles));

Comment: i got empty array

Comment: @snehapawar You are getting an empty array because you are calling `console.log` before you are setting the value.  Observables are asynchronous, so the code inside the subscribe is happening after the code outside.